# Bootstrap 3 active navbar links not working in wp?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am building a site with bootstrap 3, Bones and WP and I am having problems with displaying active links in my navbar. Have anyone else encountered this issue? Can someone spot any errors in my markup?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>/news/"><span
            class="fa fa-bookmark"></span> News
        </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>/following/">
            <span class="fa fa-eye"></span> Following
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>/followers/"><span
            class="fa fa-users"></span> Followers
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span
            class="fa fa-user"></span> My Name <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>/profile/"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>/profile/edit/"><span class="fa fa-cog"></span> Edit Profile</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>/logout"><span class="fa fa-power-off"></span> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

- I am building on top of the bones framework
- The active links work when I use bones/wp menus  so I know that it is not a stylesheet issue.